# Parsing a table using regex - Java

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I'm parsing the following `AWS` cost instance table:

```
m1.small    1   1   1.7     1 x 160    $0.044 per Hour
m1.medium   1   2   3.75    1 x 410    $0.087 per Hour
m1.large    2   4   7.5     2 x 420    $0.175 per Hour
m1.xlarge   4   8   15      4 x 420    $0.35 per Hour
```

There's a file with those costs:

```
input = new Scanner(file);
String[] values;
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = input.nextLine();
    values = line.split("\\s+"); // <-- not what I want...
    for (String v : values)
        System.out.println(v);
}
```

However that gives me:

```
m1.small
1
1
1.7
1
x
160
$0.044
per
Hour
```

which is not what I want ... A corrected parsed `values` (with the right regex) would look like this:

```
['m1.small', '1', '1', '1.7', '1 x 160', '$0.044', 'per Hour']
```

What would be the right `regex` in order to obtain the right result? One can assume the table will have always the same pattern.

Comment: Is the actual data separated with tabs? Can there be instances where columns are only delimited by one space?

Comment: @Pietu1998 Mostly ... but not necessarily ... the regex would produce something more robust ... that why I didn't move to parse with `\\t+`. Those files are huge, so it may be pointless search those files in order to fix a missing tab.

Comment: Can you use `\\s{2,}`?

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes but that gave me a problem: `1.7 1 x 160 $0.044 per Hour`

Comment: How about going the other way? Split by `\\s` and then concatenate parts of the result.

Comment: @PM77-1 I had initially thought about that ... but then its too error prone (I tried, believe me), then I decided that a regex is the best way.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/sP6zW5/1 This will help if your text is always in same format.Split is too complicated here

Comment: @amow Could you make it into an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split by one oe more spaces. And the spaces must appear in the context below.

DIGIT - SPACES - NOT "x"

or

NOT "x" - SPACES - DIGIT

```
    values = line.split("(?<=\\d)\\s+(?=[^x])|(?<=[^x])\\s+(?=\\d)")));
```

Comment: Boom! Thank you so much

Comment: @Just one more thing ... some lines have `EBS Only    $0.024`, so it should match for that too ... in this case, `['EBS Only', '$0.024']` .. I tried to add that but didn't work ...

Answer (score 5):

Try this fiddle 
https://regex101.com/r/sP6zW5/1

`([^\s]+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+([\d\.]+)\s+(\d+ x \d+)\s+(\$\d+\.\d+)\s+(per \w+)`

match the text and the group is your list.

I think use split in your case is too complicated. If the text is always the same.Just like a reverse procedure of string formatting.

Comment: amow, one more thing ... `Java` is bitching about `invalid escape sequence` ... how would I fix that?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a regular expression, you'd do this:

```
        String s = "m1.small    1   1   1.7     1 x 160    $0.044 per Hour";
        String spaces = "\\s+";
        String type = "(.*?)";
        String intNumber = "(\\d+)";
        String doubleNumber = "([0-9.]+)";
        String dollarNumber = "([$0-9.]+)";
        String aXb = "(\\d+ x \\d+)";
        String rest = "(.*)";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(type + spaces + intNumber + spaces + intNumber + spaces + doubleNumber
                + spaces + aXb + spaces + dollarNumber + spaces + rest);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String[] fields = new String[] { matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3), matcher.group(4),
                    matcher.group(5), matcher.group(6), matcher.group(7) };
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fields));
        }
```

Notice how I've broken up the regular expression to be readable. (As one long String, it is hard to read/maintain.) There's another way of doing it though. Since you know which fields are being split, you could just do this simple split and build a new array with the combined values:

```
        String[] allFields = s.split("\\s+");
        String[] result = new String[] { 
            allFields[0], 
            allFields[1],
            allFields[2],
            allFields[3],
            allFields[4] + " " + allFields[5] + " " + allFields[6],         
            allFields[7], 
            allFields[8] + " " + allFields[9] };
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```